# Tastypie serializing Virtual Field's Model

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I've `Patient`, `Doctor`, `Story` Model. Each `Story` have a `patient_id` and a `doctor_id`. I want to retrieve a list of doctors the patient have visited ever.

```
class Patient(Person):

    def visits(self):
        doctor_visits = []
        for v in self.stories.values('doctor').annotate(visits=Count('doctor')):
            # replace the doctor id with doctor object
            v['doctor'] = Doctor.objects.get(id=v['doctor'])
            doctor_visits.append(v)

        return doctor_visits
```

Here is my tastypie Resource

```
class PatientResource(ModelResource):
    stories = fields.ToManyField('patients.api.StoryResource', 'stories', null=True)
    visits = fields.ListField(attribute='visits', readonly=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Patient.objects.all()
        excludes = ['id', 'login', 'password']
```

with the above tastypie results the following

```
{
  address:"ADDRESS",
  dob:"1985-12-04",
  email:"EMAIL",
  name:"Nogen",
  resource_uri:"/patients/api/v1/patient/9/",
  sex:"M",
  stories:[
    "/patients/api/v1/story/1/",
    "/patients/api/v1/story/2/",
    "/patients/api/v1/story/4/"
  ],
  visits:[
    {
      doctor:"Dr. X",
      visits:2
    },
    {
      doctor:"Dr. Y",
      visits:1
    }
  ]
}
```

See Its caling the `__unicode__` method of `Doctor` rather I expected this to be a link `/patients/api/v1/doctor/<doctor_id>/` Do I need to construct the path manually or There is some other way around ?

I've tried using `dehydrate` possibly incorrectly

```
class PatientResource(ModelResource):
    stories = fields.ToManyField('patients.api.StoryResource', 'stories', null=True)
    visits = fields.ListField(attribute='visits', readonly=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Patient.objects.all()
        excludes = ['id', 'login', 'password']

    def dehydrate_visits(self, bundle):
        for visit in bundle.data['visits']:
            visit['doctor'] = DoctorResource(visit['doctor'])

        return bundle
```

Which Results in **maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object** Exception

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you get maximum recursion depth but your method is wrong.

```
class PatientResource(ModelResource):
    [...]

    def dehydrate_visits(self, bundle):
        # Make sure `bundle.data['visits'][0]['doctor'] isn't string.
        # If it's already dehydrated string: try use `bundle.obj.visits` instead.
        for visit in bundle.data['visits']:
            visit['doctor'] = DoctorResource.get_resource_uri(visit['doctor'])

        return bundle
```

I didn't test that. So fill free to comment if its incorrect.